# Summing 8-bit integers in __m512i with AVX intrinsics

Tags: c, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx

AVX512 provide us with intrinsics to sum all cells in a `__mm512` vector. However, some of their counterparts are missing: there is no `_mm512_reduce_add_epi8`, yet.

```
_mm512_reduce_add_ps     //horizontal sum of 16 floats
_mm512_reduce_add_pd     //horizontal sum of 8 doubles
_mm512_reduce_add_epi32  //horizontal sum of 16 32-bit integers
_mm512_reduce_add_epi64  //horizontal sum of 8 64-bit integers
```

Basically, I need to implement `MAGIC` in the following snippet.

```
__m512i all_ones = _mm512_set1_epi16(1);
short sum_of_ones = MAGIC(all_ones);
/* now sum_of_ones contains 32, the sum of 32 ones. */
```

The most obvious way would be using `_mm512_storeu_epi8` and sum the elements of the array together, but that would be slow, plus it might invalidate the cache. I suppose there exists a faster approach.

Bonus points for implementing `_mm512_reduce_add_epi16` as well.

Comment: Since you mention it's "slow" to do it naively, this implies this is performance-critical. What's the usecase here? If it's a large reduction operation, there are better ways to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `_mm512_reduce_add_epi64` does not correspond to a single AVX512 instruction, but it generates a sequence of shuffles and additions.

To reduce 64 `epu8` values to 8 `epi64` values one usually uses the [`vpsadbw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psadbw) instruction (SAD=Sum of Absolute Differences) against a zero vector, which then can be reduced further:

```
long reduce_add_epu8(__m512i a)
{
    return _mm512_reduce_add_epi64(_mm512_sad_epu8(a, _mm512_setzero_si512()));
}
```

Try it on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/1rMiPH. Unfortunately, neither GCC nor Clang seem to be able to optimize away the function if it is used with `_mm512_set1_epi16(1)`.

For `epi8` instead of `epu8` you need to first add 128 to each element (or xor with `0x80`), then reduce it using `vpsadbw` and at the end subtract `64*128` (or `8*128` on each intermediate 64bit result). [Note this was wrong in a previous version of this answer]

For `epi16` I suggest having a look at what instructions `_mm512_reduce_add_epi32` and `_mm512_reduce_add_epi64` generate and derive from there what to do.

---

Overall, as @Mysticial suggested, it depends on your context what the best approach of reducing is. E.g., if you have a very large array of `int64` and want a sum as `int64`, you should just add them together packet-wise and only at the very end reduce one packet to a single `int64`.